# 3 siblings - Need 1 to grow responsively while the other 2 stay at min-content

Tags: css

Going to do my best to explain the constraints.

There's 3 containers `.content` `.left` and `.bottom` and a resize handler to control available space.

- I need `.container` to 'grow' as the space grows to take up the available space.
- `.left` should stay at it's min-content width and 100% height and is already (great).
- `.bottom` should stay at it's min-content height and 100% width and **isn't** currently (not great).
- Cannot change the structure of the HTML because it's outside my control in real world.

Messed around for awhile with different combinations of align-items: stretch and grow but can't seem to do it when the direction is a row, but can't change it to a column without changing structure of HTML.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  flex: 1;
}

.bottom {
   border: 1px solid grey;
   flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left min content</div>
    <div class="content">should resize vertically and horizontally</div>
    <div class="bottom"/>bottom should be min content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check if this site helps, https://www.cssportal.com/css-flexbox-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this scenario we can utilize `display: grid;` properties and achieve the required behavior without changing the HTML structure, by doing something like this.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto max-content;
    height: 40rem;
    width: 20rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: both;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.bottom {
   border: 1px solid grey;
   grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left min content</div>
    <div class="content">should resize vertically and horizontally</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom should be min content</div>
</div>
```

I have simply defined 2 rows and columns, `grid-template-columns: max-content auto;` and `grid-template-rows: auto max-content;`.
then letting the 1st column take all the available height using `max-content`, and the 2nd column, which is the bottom one, stays `auto` and takes up the remaining space.

then using `grid-column: span 2;` on the bottom div. which expands it to the size of 2 rows which in our case is 100% of the width (as we only have 2 rows).

I hope this will resolve your issue.